# Remove this audit from the LQP queue

Tags: support, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I recently failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20495889). Upon reviewing, it seemed like the post seemed to answer the question, provided the main points from the article linked, and then provided the link as a reference.

Furthermore, I even went to the website and checked to see if the username matched the author in the link in question.

I believe there may be some additional information I'm not seeing (Like multiple spam posts from this user), but in all accounts this looks like a good post to me, and should not have failed. Please remove this from the LQP audit queue.

Comment: Here I was thinking LQP referred to a linear-quadratic programming question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post was deleted because a user had raised a spam flag on it. By the looks of it, it seemed spammy as it copied the answer entirely from the link, which is why it was deleted. Given that the post was deleted by a moderator after receiving a spam flag, it was chosen as an audit.

I've cleared the spam flag, and re-deleted the post with the correct reason, thereby removing the post as an audit.

Comment: Shouldn't the spam flag be removed/disputed in these circumstances? This seems harsh for a 100 rep penalty, even if it was a copy/paste (They did try to answer the question, and provided the link as well)

Comment: It was deleted without the 100 rep penalty, @FrankerZ. Mods can choose to delete spam flagged posts with either the 100 rep penalty + spamrammed  (commonly called nuke), or without (just deletion).

Comment: If it was deleted without the 100 rep penalty, why was it chosen for an audit? Shouldn't this either A) Clear the spam flags, or B) Not choose it for an audit?

Comment: That system isn't present. There have been numerous requests on mother meta for allowing mods to choose these audits while deleting a spam post. So, as long as they've been implemented, these issues occur. :\

Answer (score -12):

I will disagree on the rationale, why you believe this looks OK:

The link does explain the difference between `setValue()` and `postValue()`, but the <del>plagiarized</del> quoted part does not contain the *vital* information. In fact, it doesn't add *anything* the OP doesn't already know. If you are looking for an answer, you will need to click the link. That makes it a link-only answer.

It's subtle, and maybe not unambiguously clear to qualify as a good candidate for an audit, though.

Comment: @pnuts: It was an *attempt*, that failed to answer the question. It provided a link, and only the information from the linked article answers the question. The quoted text does nothing to provide any new, useful information. But yeah, lately *anything* is regarded as an attempt, so that we can continue to pile up low-quality contributions, in the hopes of being more inclusive. I liked the times when this place was *exclusively* for programmers.

Comment: @pnuts: All rules aside, what would happen if the linked to content went offline? Would the answer still have *any* value? That can be answered with a *"No."*. And that's all that counts when you need to distinguish between a link-only answer and a genuine answer. It doesn't matter whether the author *meant* to write a genuine answer.

Comment: @pnuts: Why do you think that I disagree with Shog9♦ here? The issue here is: The text of the proposed answer *does not* contain an honest attempt at answering the question. It is an attempt at turning a link-only answer into something that doesn't look like one, by *blindly* copying *unrelated* information. It's still a link-only answer. I'm also quite confuzzled what *"argue your case on META [not] here"* is supposed to mean. This *is* meta...

Comment: _"It was an attempt"_. _You_ said that... like three comments ago. Is it an attempt or is it not an attempt. It looks like an attempt to me. It even smells like an attempt inasmuch as my phone can smell like an attempt. I'm pretty sure it is an attempt

Comment: @TinyGiant: Is posting a link-only answer not an attempt then?

Comment: @IInspectable a link in and of itself is not an attempt. A link _with_ an attempt is an attempt just as much as an attempt without a link is an attempt.

Comment: @pnuts: The OP is asking for documentation on `setValue()` and `postValue()`. The proposed answer doesn't provide a link to documentation, nor does it attempt to explain, what they do. It does mention them, completely out of context.

Comment: So you mean that in your opinion the answer is wrong or not useful and should be downvoted. That has never been a reason to flag.

Comment: @TinyGiant: How can you post a link without attempting to post a link? I'm afraid, whatever you were trying to get across, that attempt failed terribly.